# Bootstrap 5, dropdown button issue

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

hope you're well! I am having a problem with this navbar, basically, I added a dropdown button inside the navbar but once I click the arrow to get the button collapse Its look like is collapsing behind the "body" so it doesn't show properly. in attachment the picture. and this is my code:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark" id="navbar"> <!--this wrap all the navbar-->
        <div class="container-fluid"> <!--this class provides a responsive fixed width container-->

                                                                      <!-- this code is to add symbols  using bootstrap icon library  -->
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                
                                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-exclude" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                                <path d="M0 2a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h8a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v2h2a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v8a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H6a2 2 0 0 1-2-2v-2H2a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V2zm12 2H5a1 1 0 0 0-1 1v7h7a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V4z"/>
                                                </svg> 
                                                                    <!-- end symbol  -->
              VRQ: Vincenzo's Random "Quotes"</a>
            
              
            
              <div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle btn-sm" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton2" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                      Dropdown button
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-dark" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton2">
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item active" href="#">Action</a></li>
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                      <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>

                  
                <div> <!--div container of all the buttons-->

                                                             
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary " type="button" style="width:150px" id="btncontactme">Contact Me</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary " type="button" id="btnsignup">Sign Up </button>
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary " type="button" id="btnlogin">Log In</button>   
                    
                </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
     
    <!-- END NAVBAR -->
```

[image: collapse image]

thank you in advance for the answers

Comment: Are you able to share more of the code? Do you have any custom styles? It looks like your navigation has `overflow: hidden` set on it which prevents it's any children elements from being visible if they expand outside of the element with hidden overflow. There is nothing in your current HTML that would cause the issue seen in the image

Comment: @Simp4Code Yes! the problem was that! In my CSS I have the navbar with overflow: hidden. just deleted that one and now it's working fine!! thank you very much you are the best :3